# External Javascript Alert function

Tags: javascript, function, onload

I am new to writing in HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. My question is, what is the method to creating an onLoad function to an external JavaScript file?

I am attempting this using Notepad++. The external JavaScript file is known as "demo.js" within my "js" folder.

Comment: i don't understand you what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

Your `demo.js` should be linked to the page as shown below (in the `<head>` tag).

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can run a function on load using

**Demo.js**

```
window.onload=function(){
    alert('Hello World!');
}
```

Or you can have window.onload call a function

```
function MyFunction(){
    alert('Hello World!');
}
window.onload=MyFunction;
```

If you have any questions, leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

As long as the external file is loaded and the desired function is available you can simply use it as-is. Pass it to the `onload` attribute or use it as a callback handler in your code.

The fact that the code is "physically" in a different file shouldn't matter to your `onload` function - as long as the function is accessible it will be executed.